# Elements of my array are duplicated with .map function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm triyng to mix two arrays with .map() and .filter(), but my elements are doubled, tripled and more.

My two arrays are,

```
a = [
      [ "id", 1536 ],
      [ "origin", "ModèleLogiciel" ],
      [ "target", "ModèleDomaine" ],
      [ "type", "CONCERNE" ],
      [ "EAI", "reel" ]
    ]
```

and

```
b = [ "EAI", "Fréquence" ]
```

I want to add the values of the second array in the first one, like this :

```
a = [
      [ "id", 1536 ],
      [ "origin", "ModèleLogiciel" ],
      [ "target", "ModèleDomaine" ],
      [ "type", "CONCERNE" ],
      [ "EAI", "reel" ],
      [ "Fréquence", "" ]
    ]
```

I've done :

```
    a.map((col) => {
        return (
            b.filter((x) => {
                if (col[0] !== x) {
                    a.push([x, ""]);
                }
            })
        );
    });
```

and my result :

```
a = [
        ["id", 1536],
        ["origin", "ModèleLogiciel"],
        ["target", "ModèleDomaine"],
        ["type", "CONCERNE"],
        ["EAI", "reel"],
        ["Fréquence", ""],
        ["EAI", ""],
        ["Fréquence", ""],
        ["EAI", ""],
        ["Fréquence", ""],
        ["EAI", ""],
        ["Fréquence", ""],
    ];
```

I have to misuse the .map function, I presume. And I have trouble removing duplicates.

Someone have a solution for me :) ?

Comment: Do you want to add the new items like `"EAI"` only if it doesn't exist in the `0` index of inner arrays?

Comment: Yes exactelly, it's what i'm trying to do !

Comment: I corrected my question to be clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use concat

```js
a.concat(b.map(x => [x, '']))
```

update:

maybe you want to add `b` value that only not exist in `a`. that's why you want to use `filter`.

you can do it like this:

```js
a.concat(b.filter(x => a.find(y => y[0] == x) == null).map(x => [x, '']))
```

Comment: Ye, you understood what i wanted to do !! but your solution doesn't work :(

Comment: @reckyt give me more information how doesn't not work.

Comment: Well I copyed your solution but the values of b are not added

Comment: I check your example angin. my code was worked. you forget a comma after `[ "type", "CONCERNE" ]` in your example.

Comment: Can you write your solution in a code snippet so I can run it, please :D

Answer (score 1):

Use array spread to combine between array `a`, and the result of mapping array `b` to the required form:

```js
const a = [["id",1536],["origin","ModèleLogiciel"],["target","ModèleDomaine"],["type","CONCERNE"]]
const b = [ "EAI", "Fréquence" ]

const result = [
  ...a, // add a
  ...b.map(v => [v, ""]) // transform b and add it 
]

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map new arrays and push them to the goven array.

```js
const
    a = [["id", 1536], ["origin", "ModèleLogiciel"], ["target", "ModèleDomaine"], ["type", "CONCERNE"]],
    b = ["EAI", "Fréquence"];

a.push(...b.map(value => [value, '']));

console.log(a);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

First merge using spread operators, then using a map and create a new array.
I would also check if the given input is not an array.

```js
var a = [
  ["id", 1536],
  ["origin", "ModèleLogiciel"],
  ["target", "ModèleDomaine"],
  ["type", "CONCERNE"],
];
var b = ["EAI", "Fréquence"];

var result = [...a, ...b].map((i) => i instanceof Array ? i : [i, ""]);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `b.forEach()` to push new array items into `a`:

```js
const a = [["id", 1536], ["origin", "ModèleLogiciel"], ["target", "ModèleDomaine"], ["type", "CONCERNE"]];
const b = ["EAI", "Fréquence"];

b.forEach(x => a.push([x, ""]));

console.log(a);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```